# What to do with my obsolete / wrong answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

I wrote an answer to this questions:
[Why are cambions unable to reproduce amongst each other?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/124999/why-are-cambions-unable-to-reproduce-amongst-each-other/)

It received a lot of positive attention and showed signs (at first) of being a helpful answer. However, it turns out I missed an important criterion in the question that my answer does not meet...to the point that it's basically a wrong answer (ie. not helpful to the OP). I edited the answer to make it clear to further viewers that it's not really a valid answer.

After further discussion with the OP, I see no elegant amendment I can make to my answer...I would personally consider it obsolete. What is the right thing to do? Should I delete it? Re-edit to declare it obsolete? Something else...?

Comment: Ash makes pretty good points, I would add that you *can* delete your answer.  There's even the disciplined badge(https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/37/disciplined) for that.  Just an option, not a suggestion.

Comment: I believe you lose some rep for that...though I can't remember for sure...

Answer (score 1):

An answer that is not that helpful to the OP is not in point of fact not useful, just have a look at the number of times the [Populist Badge](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/39/populist) has been awarded; and the rafts of other cases where the accepted answer is not the highest scoring answer, but not to quite such an extent. A question that scores highly is useful to the people who vote for it even if the OP considers it "suboptimal".

In answer to your question let the answer stand; as is or with an edit to point out that it may not be as useful as it first appears at your discretion.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is good, and fine. It is the question that is confused, and seems to be ever evolving. As it stands, I nominated teh question for deletion because it doesn't make sense (at least, not without the comments below).

I'd leave your answer, see how the question is edited, and then see where you are at.

In any case, the OP changed the requirements after you posted, so the onus on him is to fix it, or else we would suggest rolling back the question to its earlier state.

Comment: (I don't think the OP had changed their requirements; it's just that a particular requirement wasn't explicitly clear, and I missed it when I read the question. But thanks...based on your and @Ash's advice, I'll leave my answer up!)